# vim xptemplate shortcut not working

Tags: vim

I have vim running on a remote server (connecting via the Terminal app on a Mac).  It uses pathogen to manage plugins and has xptemplate installed.

Recently the  that triggers xptemplate when you've inserted a keyword has stopped working.  I can't think of anything I've changed.

If I do:

```
verbose imap <C-\>
```

it seems to be there:

```
i  <C-\>       * <C-R>=XPTemplateStart(0,{'k':'<C-\++'})<CR>
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/xptemplate/plugin/xptemplate.conf.vim
```

Any suggestions how to further debug it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried following this "trouble shooting" to track the problem?:
https://github.com/drmingdrmer/xptemplate/wiki/FAQ